# Injected jquery, angular code does not work all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mixitup

I injected script to a web page and it shows simple list which I can change from list view to grid view. It looks like this:

[image]

When I click button "NEXT" I change my angular state and the view changes to another HTML. In that other HTML file I have a button "BACK" which changes state back to this list template, but after I click back button I go to first template and the view looks like this:

[image]

Moreover the view changing buttons from list to grid does not work anymore...

I do not know if I should paste my code in this question. But is this the problem with Angular or maybe jQuery? Any other function "check all" or "scroll" works just fine

**UPDATE**

I'm creating Google Chrome extension and for making list/grid views I am using MixItUp library

This is my List controller which controls the view in the pictures:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ListController', ListController);

ListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$state'];

function ListController($scope, $http, $location, $state) {

    var $frame = $('#smart');
    var $wrap = $frame.parent();
    var layout = 'list',
        $container = $('#ContainerSelect'),
        $changeLayouttoList = $('#toLongListSelect'),
        $changeLayoutToGrid = $('#toGridViewSelect');

    // Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
        itemNav: 'basic',
        smart: 1,
        mouseDragging: 1,
        touchDragging: 1,
        releaseSwing: 1,
        startAt: 1,
        scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
        scrollBy: 1,
        speed: 300,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        dragHandle: 1,
        dynamicHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1
    });

    $container.mixItUp({
        animation: {
            animateChangeLayout: true,
            animateResizeTargets: true,
            effects: 'fade rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(-100px)'
        },
        layout: {
            containerClass: 'list'
        }
    });

    // assign function to onclick property of checkbox
    document.getElementById('checkbox_field').onclick = function () {
        // access properties using this keyword
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".selectProductCB").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
            $(".checkbox_txt").text("Uncheck all");
        } else {
            $(".selectProductCB").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
            $(".checkbox_txt").text("Check all");
        }
    };

    $scope.next = function () {
        $state.go("selectNotifier", {}, { location: false });
    };

    $scope.toLongList = function () {
        layout = 'list';
        $container.mixItUp('changeLayout', {
            containerClass: layout
        });
    };

    $scope.toGridView = function () {
        layout = 'grid';
        $container.mixItUp('changeLayout', {
            containerClass: layout
        });
    };
};
```

This is Notifycontroller which has back button:

```
angular.module('app').controller('NotifyController', NotifyController);

NotifyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$state'];

function NotifyController($scope, $http, $location, $state) {
    $scope.back = function () {
        $state.go("selectList", {}, { location: false });
    };
    $scope.watchIt = function () {
        $state.go("target", {}, { location: false });
    }
};
```

With this function I am jumping through states:

```
 $scope.close = function () {
    $state.go("selectList", {}, { location: false });
};
```

Comment: sharing code would help. Are you using any third party control ?

Comment: It could be either, post some minimal code. The JQuery that changes the layout, and the angular to the next buttons

Comment: I updated my question - @rupampatel2006

Answer (score 0):

By default Angular provides/persists State. you do not need to save it. There must a an issue with list/grid view flags/variables when you click on Back Button.